# Compose AndroidView don't show my customView

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, composable

I'm trying to reuse a customView inside a compose view. I follow the guidelines to achive this, but I can't display my customView in the DefaultPreview and when run the application no show nothing.

This is that I'm trying:

```
@Composable
fun Total() {
    Row(Modifier.padding(top = 24.dp)
        .fillMaxWidth(),
        horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween) {

        AndroidView(
            factory = { context ->
                // Creates custom view
                CustomView(context).apply {
                    
                }
            },
        )

        Column(modifier = Modifier.align(Alignment.Bottom)) {
            Text("Total",
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                textAlign = TextAlign.End,
                fontSize = 12.sp,
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.app_grey_dark))

            Text("1 €",
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                textAlign = TextAlign.End,
                fontSize = 18.sp,
                color = colorResource(id = R.color.app_black_dark))
        }
    }
}
```

Java view code:

```
public class CustomView extends FrameLayout {
    ...
    ...
private Scene myView;

    public CustomView(@NonNull Context context) {
            super(context);
        }
    
        public CustomView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);
        }
    
        public CustomView(@NonNull Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
            super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
        }
    
        @Override
        protected void onFinishInflate() {
            super.onFinishInflate();
            screenRoot = findViewById(R.id.scene_root_myView);
            initControlAddToCardOne();
            myView.enter();
            TransitionInflater transitionInflater = TransitionInflater.from(getContext());
            transitionManager = transitionInflater.inflateTransitionManager(R.transition.scene_transition_manager,
                    screenRoot);
        }



   private void initControlAddToCardOne() {
    myView= Scene.getSceneForLayout(screenRoot, R.layout.my_layout, getContext());
myView.setEnterAction(() -> {
                ViewGroup defaultView = myView.getSceneRoot();
   
                });
            });
}
```

Layout xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img_button"
        android:layout_width="48dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:src="@drawable/image"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2):

AndroidView require width and height，use modifier:

```
AndroidView(
    modifier = Modifier
        .fillMaxWidth()
        .height(100.dp),
    factory = { context ->
        CustomView(context = context)
    },
    update = {
           
    }
)
```